Postgres pro 15. PgAgent не выполняет batch скрипт
День добрый.
Пытаюсь настроить выполнение скрипта на postgres Pro в pgagent.
Проблема в том, что batch вида "echo AAA" завершается с ошибкой, в статистике поле "output" пустое.
На другом сервере PostgreSQL + pgagent batch вида "echo AAA" как положено выводит "ААА" в в статистику в поле "output".
При этом нормально работают задания с sql скриптами - "vacuum full analyze;" и т.п.
В чем может быть проблема?
